# Test if SearchFind found something or Not

Tags: excel, replace, vba

I recorded this simple SearchFind macro, is there away to reference either how many cells it found with the search value

Or

A true false test so that if Searchfind found a cell with the search value then do something, else do something different.

Thanks (I hope I was clear)

```
Sub Macro2()
Columns("B:B").Select
Cells.Find(What:="MyValue", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
    :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase _
    :=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: For the answers below to make sense, it's just this: `Find` returns a `Range` type. To check if a range exists, you use a simple test of `If Rng Is Nothing`. Same here: assign the `Find` to a variable, then check if it's nothing. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim rng As Range

    With Columns("B:B")
        Set rng = .Find(What:="MyValue", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            'do something if "MyValue" is found
            Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
        Else
            'do something if "MyValue" is NOT found
        End If
    End With        
End Sub
```

> how many cells it found with the search value

you can use:

```
MsgBox WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns("B:B"), "MyValue")
```

also I suggest you to qualify your range `Columns("B:B")`, i.e. better to use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:B")`

Comment: Worked great thanks.  simoco I will fpllow this advice `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:B")` but will give a brief reason as to why this is advisable, also dose `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:B")` advisable aswel often my code is in one workbook and works on a different workbook.  Thank you again.

Comment: `why this is advisable` - actually when you're using just `Columns("B:B")` - you always refers to _avtive_ sheet of _active_ workbook. What to use either `ThisWorkbook...` or `ActiveWorkbook...` depends on your needs, but the differense is that `ThisWorkbook` always refers to workbook _from where code runs_, and `ActiveWorkbook` - as name suggests, refers to _active_ workbook.

Answer (score 2):

You can check determine whether or not something was found like this:

```
Dim FoundRng As Range

'this search step is the same as yours, but assigns the result to a range rather than activating the cell
Set FoundRng = Cells.Find(What:="MyValue", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
    :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase _
    :=False, SearchFormat:=False)

'check whether or not the range is "nothing"
If FoundRng Is Nothing Then
    'the value was NOT found, do something
Else
    'the value WAS found, do something else
End If
```